# CSS border effecting width when resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I made two simple navigation menu using `ul` and `li`. One without border and another with border. The width of the both menu is fixed with 400px.

In ther first menu I gave each `li` a fixed width of 100px and in the second menu according the width calculation I gave fixed width of 98px and 1px border on left and right which in total is 100px for each `li`.

Now my question is when I am resizing the the browser resolution using the "Ctrl + -" the first menu stays as it is in any resolution but in the second menu the last element is shifting to the next line under the first element.

I want to know why this happens and how to resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/jhz56/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The border width doesn't scale together with the li width, that's why the menu breaks. So one solution can simply be:

```
.nav2 ul li {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jhz56/1/

Comment: Basically means that because you have a set width of 400px, and if you make the viewport smaller/bigger, that width has to scale. The problem is the border still retains its own width (it cannot go smaller than 1px), which makes the entire menu mess up. The `border-box` settings essentially treats the border as part of the entire element (instead of separate), which allows it to scale much more gracefully

Answer (score 1):

This issue is simple. You are saying you have set the width using `px`, which will also change once you are changing the screen size, so to minimize this error. I will recommend using `%` so that in every screen size, it should always have its own width and height

This way, it won't come out of its box. I have checked your fiddle, both of the lists were on their place no matter how much zooming.

Second thing that you can is to use `Media Query` to make sure that the with each screen size, the element gets a new style to fir perfectly to the screen size and the needs.

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>+</kbd>, the elements get a zoom and are more likely to take more pixels from the browser. Which makes it go a block downwards to fit to the width provided, when you press <kbd>-</kbd> the element shrinks and goes near to the left `li`. This way, their properties shift.

Here is a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/7SbLR/ When you try zooming in or out, the element will change its widths and all that other properties.

You can use `min-width` and `max-width` instead of `width`. To make sure, it always gets the total width as its min and max.

```
div {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 500px; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/7SbLR/1/ In this fiddle, slight zooming in and out won't cause an error in the UI, but it doesn't work for alot of zooming (250%+). So here media query will be the option.

This way, even if you zoom in or out, the element will always have a width of `500px`. This might be handy for you!