# How to stop divs moving under each other when zooming out

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code to create a vertical navigation bar:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Hello</a></li>
    <li><a>Hello</a></li>
    <li><a>Hello</a></li>
    <li><a>Hello</a></li>
    <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="stream">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

#nav {
  width: 239px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  float: left;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

#nav ul li a {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #1A6680;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
}

#stream {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 719px;
  height: 550px;
  background: #007A5C;
  float: right;
}
```

While this normally works fine, if you zoom out, the `#nav` goes on top of the `#stream`, instead of side by side. How do I make sure that the `#nav` and `#stream` `div`s remain side by side and touching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When "zooming out" in a browser, the browser attempts to compensate for border. You've set your border to 1px, but at 50% zoom, the border is actually rendered with a width of 2 pixels.

The reason for this is that when the browser reduces the size of the elements it is displaying it attempts to do this to the border. But as you've only specified a 1-pixel width border it will first calculate a width of less than 1. As you cannot show a portion of a pixel the browser attempts to compensate.

However it over-compensates and multiplies the original value with the scale of the zoom. So at 50%, the border is calculated at

> 1 * 0.5

This returns 1.5 and is scaled up to 2.

So, there will be several resolutions to this problem.

1. You can either adjust the width of your boxes and borders to
   compensate for any modifications the browser will make.
2. You can use percentage widths to make the page responsive as suggested by Fahad.
3. Or you can use CSS3's box-sizing attribute (if you're not too concerned with fallback to older browsers);

   ```
   #stream {
       text-align: center;
       border: 1px solid #000;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       width: 719px;
       height: 550px;
       background: #007A5C;
       float: right;
   }
   ```

   Taken from [Sunny's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19617257/3990156)

I'm sure there will be other resolutions to this, but I believe these to be your best three options.