# CSS - Fixed border width change when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, browser, flexbox, border

I made 2 simple link buttons that are located within 2 `div` tags.

This is the `css` and `html` code I tried:

```css
.lang-box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 2%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-direction-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.border-gold {
  border: 2px solid #ac8b45;
}

.text-gold {
  color: #ac8b45;
}

.background-gold {
  background-color: #ac8b45;
}

.text-black {
  color: #000;
}

.no-background {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.lang-a-button {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.lang-a-button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang-box">
  <div class="flex-container flex-direction-column border-gold">
    <a href="/en" target="_self" class="lang-a-button no-background text-gold" title="Change to English">EN</a>
    <a href="/" target="_self" class="active_lang lang-a-button text-black background-gold" title="Cambia in Italiano">IT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the final result:

[image: this is the final result]

The problem is that the right border of `.border-gold` changes in thickness when I resize the browser screen:

[image: Problem with border 1]
[image: Problem with border 2]

I don't understand why this happens. I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19617257/9208870) but nothing changes.

I use Google Chrome v69 for testing.

Do I need to add something?

Comment: are you zooming?

Comment: No, only resize browser window

Comment: Try fix width for link button & wrap, like this ~ https://jsbin.com/bonateq/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I can't reproduce that with resize (using Chrome), zooming though, give the described issue

Comment: When zooming one get rounding issues which can cause this. One way is to use an absolute positioned pseudo element that overflow the button on each side, with the 1px or 2px, having its border or background color set to the same as the main border. If you with that get an unwanted overflow on the flex container, set `hidden` to its `overflow`.

Comment: @HamSter Your solution is the best one. However I want to have a concrete answer to the problem, because this is not the first time it happens. Why i have to give a fixed size to the main container `.lang-box`?
The `a` tags should be wrapped by the external DIVs, or i'm wrong?

Comment: @LGSon I made a [gif](https://imgur.com/cP6UY5i) that show the problem

Comment: @inGranator We can't debug an image. You need to provide a code snippet, within the question, which reproduce the issue, or else no one can suggest a proper solution (other than throwing guesses).

Comment: @inGranator, I have no answer but i think that this is because of the peculiarity `flex` & `flex-direction: column`. Even when we set the fixed width of the element inside flex block, it does not always take it into account. Therefore, for blocks with a fixed width, you need to additionally specify `flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;`. So ... for `flex-direction: column` ... add fix width for wrap & inner link. ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add links `flex-grow:0;   flex-shrink:0;` and fixed width, like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lang-box {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 60px;
    left: 2%; 
    z-index: 3;
  
  width: 42px;
}

.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-direction-column{
    flex-direction: column;
}

.border-gold{
    border: 2px solid #ac8b45;
}

.text-gold{
  color: #ac8b45;
}

.background-gold{
    background-color: #ac8b45;
}

.text-black{
    color: #000;
}

.no-background{
  background-color: transparent;
}

.lang-a-button{
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    /* padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px; */
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
  
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow:0;
  flex-shrink:0;
  width: 40px;
}

.lang-a-button:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang-box">
    <div class="flex-container flex-direction-column border-gold">
         <a href="/en" target="_self" class="lang-a-button no-background text-gold" title="Change to English">EN</a>
          <a href="/" target="_self" class="active_lang lang-a-button text-black background-gold" title="Cambia in Italiano">IT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not have an exact answer but i think that this is because of the peculiarity `flex` & `flex-direction: column`. Even when we set the fixed width of the element inside `flex` block, it does not always take it into account. Therefore, for blocks with a fixed width, you need to additionally specify `flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;`.

*So ... for `flex-direction: column` ... add fix width for wrap & inner links.*